# LogIn authentication similar to bank apps in codename one

Tags: android, authentication, codenameone

I want to create a login authentication for my application.. like bank app once logged out it should terminate the session for user...
I have created one.. but on android, if I am pressing back button on phone it still goes to the previous page...so I think I am not doing it any secure way... any example help.?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
myLoginForm.setBackCommand("", null, e -> Display.getInstance().exitApplication());
```

Comment: Hi Chen, thank you for your response. I did that....

I still have a couple of questions regarding login authentication in the app I created.... 

1. I want to store login authentication details in app and carry it through all the subsequence pages(like session in website) and terminate it once user logs out.. How can I code it..?

2. And some of my app screen appears based on the response from web service (like list of near by restaurants), how I can go back to this page with out calling webservice..?

Comment: 1. Save a variable in a class. 2. Show the form

Comment: Simply showing the form on back button will display blank form... Is it possible the data I retrieved from web service on screen stored in some memory and display it on the back button without calling webservice?

Comment: Storing the data in memory is your responsibility as it's a part of the app logic.